# Benefits of blocking the cart page to only 1 special item per order? e-commerce

Tags: e-commerce, checkout

I have a client with a particular project of blocking the purchase of a "special item" to only 1 per order.

The user cannot purchase another item in conjunction with this special item, so if the user wants another product, will need to make another purchase?

- What are the benefits of having this?
- This will disrupt for sure the basket-checkout flow?
- User will get piss off?
- How any system can insure to block users with different accounts, or cards but with the same address or even different address?
- or is a good sale if a user purchases the item 10x on 10 different orders?

I totally disagree with this approach of penalizing the user and the experience or the flow because of only 1 item. I don't see any retailer following that technique.

Any ideas, suggestion or own experiences or similar?
I'll appreciate all your help.

Comment: Maybe it is a special discount that the client doesn't want the customer to take advantage of. Why don't you ask your client? What is your question specifically? How to implement such a restriction in an online shop?

Comment: It would be helpful to understand why your client doesn't want to make additional money - what are the constraints causing this requirement?

Comment: Incredible. If I were to be served with this at any site I probably just wouldn't bother and leave immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will be work

- If user want two products (a normal and special), will have to pay to cargo, rate, two times
- Pay two times can make the user give up the purchase
- The user project your knowledge about other sites in our sites, change the experience about this, for me is not usual and cool.

To solve this problem, I recommend investigate with the main users.